# Mustache Page Break

Tags: php, html, mustache

I want building a form like that:

```
<div> test </div>
```

// show me all categories from table

```
<div class="section">
{{#categories}}
 {{{.}}}
{{/categories}}
</div>
```

// show me all books from table>

```
<div class="section">
{{#books}}
   {{{.}}}
{{/books}}
</div>
```

Each books or categories has div tag.

i want that each  tag start on new page.

Can you tell me how can i insert new page in mustache.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I found something: 
From html is posible, something like `<p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>`.
After this line, new page is made.